# Markdown in Svelte with links needing target attribute and using the svelte-markdown npm package

Tags: markdown, svelte, svelte-component

So, we have a Svelte component that uses the svelte-markdown package to render Markdown into readable text on the frontend, which works great until it comes to rendering links. I need to always have the target attribute and cannot figure out how to do this. Their online documentation is minimal. Can anyone offer suggestions?

Here is the relevant code as it stands currently:

```
<script lang="ts">
import SvelteMarkdown from 'svelte-markdown';
import LinkComponent from './MDRenderer.svelte';

export let response: string = "";
let responseEl: HTMLElement;
</script>

<div class="prose max-w-[80%] text-white text-ellipsis overflow-x-hidden mb-8" bind:this={responseEl}>
<SvelteMarkdown source={response} renderers={{link: LinkComponent}} />
</div>
```

I did try creating a custom component following their online docs with the following code and importing it, but the links were still rendered without the target attribute.

```
<script>
export let href = "";
export let title = undefined;
</script>

<a {href} {title} target="_blank"><slot /></a>
```

Comment: Are you passing the Svelte component to the SvelteMarkdown component?

Comment: Yes, I am. Sorry forgot to mark that in the code above. I will update for better clarity.

Comment: Ok, now you are passing something called MDRenderer that doesn't exist in the code you present.  You import as LinkComponent.  I guess you mean LinkComponent.  Best if you could post a live demo at the Svelte.dev REPL, or codesandbox.io or stackblitz.